# A word for: trends were in both directions (negative/positive or decreasing/increasing)

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a sentence as follows. Background knowledge is that the temporal trends in the use of different types of hospital care were bidirectional/involving both increasing and decreasing changes/diversified...

Or in other words:

- the use of some hospital care types increased (change shown in percentages)
- the use of some hospital care types decreased (change shown in percentages)

> Trends in the use of different types of hospital care were **[need a good word here]**.

Comment: Are the increasing and decreasing changes both improvements? (Say, increasing patient satisfaction and decreasing per patient costs) Or is one dimension sometimes getting better, sometimes getting worse? (Say nursing staff satisfaction improving for one year and getting worse in another)

Comment: Thanks! I had a little error in the initial post. There were many hospital care types, some increased, some decreased.

Comment: "care types" aren't really things that can "increase" or "decrease" (unless you're referring to *the **number** of patients being treated by any given "care type"*). I don't know exactly what you're getting at here, but I think it would probably make more sense to talk about things ***improving / deteriorating*** rather than ***increasing / decreasing***.

Comment: Good point. I added to the initial post that these changes are shown in percentages (figure in manuscript).

Comment: Could you remove your acceptation? My answer is based on a misunderstanding and therefore an error but I can't delete because it's been accepted. Sorry for this little problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omni-directional - although omni means all, so potentially does not define the meaning accurately.